# How do run MYSQL scripts from a shell script with bash variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mysql

Im making a script where I connect to a database, look for a value and then if that value returned something then I will do something else.

```
ip=$("variable is defined here")
```

Then I connect to the MYSQL database using:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot --password=*
```

However, this takes me to another prompt, and I need to run another command from that, I can't get it to work.

I tried this:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql "MYSQL argumens;";
```

and just:

```
MYSQL arguments;
```

None of these work and I have to pass a variable to it, what can I do now?

Comment: You might find the DBA SE useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#! bin/bash
selectvar="SELECT * FROM test;"

mysql --user=root --password=mypass database << eof 
$selectvar
eof
```

Answer (score 3):

To execute statements from the command line without an interactive prompt, use the `-e` option:

```
mysql mydb -e 'select * from foo'
```